# Why does repeated JSON parsing consume more and more memory?

Tags: ruby, json, memory, memory-leaks

It seems that parsing the same JSON file over and over again in Ruby uses increasingly larger amounts of memory. 
Consider the code and the output below:

1. Why isn't the memory freed up after the first iteration?
2. Why does a 116MB JSON file take up 1.5Gb of RAM after parsing? It's surprising considering the text file is converted into hashes. What am I missing here?

Code:

```
require 'json'

def memused
  `ps ax -o pid,rss | grep -E "^[[:space:]]*#{$$}"`.strip.split.map(&:to_i)[1]/1024
end

text = IO.read('../data-grouped/2012-posts.json')
puts "before parsing: #{memused}MB"
iter = 1
while true
  items = JSON.parse(text)
  GC.start
  puts "#{iter}: #{memused}MB"
  iter += 1
end
```

Output:

```
before parsing: 116MB
1: 1840MB
2: 2995MB
3: 2341MB
4: 3017MB
5: 2539MB
6: 3019MB
```

Comment: The garbage collector runs when it wants to, which has nothing to do with when *you* want it to...

Comment: Shouldn't the GC run when the program is running out of memory? When the json is 400mb it uses 5gigs of ram on the first iter and starts using swap afterwards (which makes the parsing take tens of minutes instead of seconds). How would I invoke the GC to clean that memory up?

Comment: Which versions of Ruby and JSON are being used?

Comment: Do you mean "MB" instead of "Mb"? In my world "MB" means MegaBytes and "Mb" means Megabits, which are a little different.

Comment: Yes, I mean Megabytes. Changed to MB. I'm using ruby 2.0.0-p0. Not sure how to find out json version. It seems I don't have a json gem installed but the code still works.. `gem check json` doesn't return anything

Comment: You're using the JSON built-into Ruby then.

Comment: I'm curious about this problem. Do you have an example JSON file that you could share for folks to attempt to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Don't have the data any longer unfortunately. It was just a very large  array of non hierarchical json associative maps.

Answer (score 4):

When Ruby parses a JSON file, it creates many intermediate objects to achieve the goal. These objects stays on memory until GC start working.

If the JSON file has a complicated structure, many arrays and inner objects, the number will grow fast too.

Did you try to call "GC.start" to suggest Ruby clean up unused memory? If the amount of memory 
decrease significantly, its suggest that is just intermediate objects used to parse the data, otherwise, your data structure is complex or there is something your data that the lib can't deallocate.

For large JSON processing I use yajl-ruby (https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby). It is C implemented and has a low footprint.

Comment: thanks, I'll do that. That doesn't answer my questions though.

Comment: @user1027996 I edited the post and included some informations.

Comment: adding GC.start doesn't make a difference

Comment: @user1027996: JSON might be creating symbols and such, which may end up as memory leaks since they're never freed.

Comment: Also as I know `GC.start` doesn't force garbage collection but only you make suggestion for interpreter that you would be happy if it run there. And +1 for `yajl`.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier You are right! On my experience, when you have enough amount of unused data, it costume to run the GC. I don't use it on my implementations, but I used it to figure out what is happenning. I will make the answer clear. Tks